# Trigger with two tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a flight database with several tables. I'm attempting to make a trigger to deny an insert or update on a flight that has a maintenance request. If the plane is requested for maintenance, there shouldn't be a flight between these times. I get the error message just fine, but it seems I always get it. How come? Thanks in advance, I always appreciate the help.

```
alter trigger DateMaintenanceTrigger 
on Flight
after update, insert 
as
    select 
        m.StartDate, m.TargetEndDate, f.DepartureDateID
    from 
        Maintenance.MaintenanceRequest as m
    inner join 
        Flight as f on f.PlaneID = m.PlaneID
    where 
        f.DepartureDateID < m.TargetEndDate 
        and f.DepartureDateID > m.StartDate

    begin 
        raiserror ('Flight cannot take place on this maintentance date, plane not ready.', 16,1);
        rollback transaction;
        return
    end;
    go


insert into Flight 
values (304, 3, 1, 200192, 1, '20160916 09:00:00 AM');
```

Comment: What are the values of f.DepartureDateID, m.TargetEndDate and m.StartDate, is f.DepartureDateID really a date in the same format as the others?

Comment: They are all datetime types. I try to make a flight in the year 2020, where all my maintenance requests are in 2016, and I still get my trigger error message.

Comment: 2016-09-16 08:30:00.000 Start - 2016-09-17 09:30:00.000 End. Is a maintenance request date. If i use this insert on a date, still get the error message. '20200916 09:00:00 AM'

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is happening because you are missing the IF clause and also you are joining with the complete flight table, i.e. if atlease one flight matches yours criteria you will be getting the error. for the correct implementation you need to join with the inserted.PlaneID  instead as I have shown below

```
alter trigger DateMaintenanceTrigger on Flight
after update, insert 
as
IF EXISTS (
select m.StartDate, m.TargetEndDate, f.DepartureDateID
from Maintenance.MaintenanceRequest as m
JOIN inserted as i
ON i.PlaneID = m.PlaneID
and i.DepartureDateID < m.TargetEndDate and i.DepartureDateID > m.StartDate
)
    begin 
        raiserror ('Flight cannot take place on this maintentance date, plane not ready.', 16,1);
        rollback transaction;
        return
    end;
    go



insert into Flight values (304, 3, 1, 200192, 1, '20160916 09:00:00 AM');
```

Comment: insert into Flight values (304, 3, 1, 200192, 1, '20200916 09:00:00 AM');
I tried using the year 2020 in a flight and i still get the error, all of my maintenance requests are in the year 2016.

Comment: inserted.PlaneID is redlined, and theres two where clauses. wouldnt I have two 'and'?

Comment: I have to join the inserted table, added that now.

Comment: Thank you. But im still getting a redline on the where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved it by now but if not I can try to help. Try to do it like this, i tried it locally just with  a true/false query and it should work as long as your query is ok, i'm not so sure where it's most correct to put the rollback by the way, now i put it in the catch function but perhaps it's better before the raiserror().

```
alter trigger DateMaintenanceTrigger 
on Flight
after update, insert 
as

BEGIN TRY  
    IF EXISTS(
        select 
            m.StartDate, m.TargetEndDate, f.DepartureDateID
        from 
            Maintenance.MaintenanceRequest as m
        inner join 
            Flight as f on f.PlaneID = m.PlaneID
        where 
            f.DepartureDateID < m.TargetEndDate 
            and f.DepartureDateID > m.StartDate
    )
    BEGIN
        raiserror ('Flight cannot take place on this maintentance date, plane not ready.', 16,1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        insert into Flight values (304, 3, 1, 200192, 1, '20160916 09:00:00 AM');
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();  
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();  
    SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    rollback transaction;

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  
               @ErrorSeverity, 
               @ErrorState 
               );  
END CATCH;
```